# SSRS - Recovering report on smtp failure

Tags: reporting-services, smtp, snapshot

Shortly, is it possible to recover the report that was generated by SSRS when SMTP fails?

Sometimes we have network problems with SMTP and even the report was generated it couldn't be sent. We can send them manually later, but the problem is that most reports needs to be generated at a specific time, otherwise data my not be correct (for example, end of day reports needs to be generated at 12:00am, otherwise some updated numbers may not be correct. But we want to resend the report generated at 12:00am when we come to work in the morning)

I considered sending these reports though snapshots but some report subscriptions have parameters, and I couldn't find how to take snapshot for each subscription.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,
Onur

Comment: I take it this is an SSRS subscription report?

Answer (score 0):

You could capture the data each day at 12am using a sql agent job which executes a stored procedure to populate a table/tables with the data.

If this is a report which can also be run live, you would run the report based on a hidden parameter @extract_type indicating whether or not this is live or snapshot.  The default would be "live" and the subscription would pass "snapshot" for this parameter.  The code in each dataset would filter based on @extract_type, perhaps through a view.

This way, the subscription could be re-run at any time of day with the same report results.

Answer (score 0):

well, first you're not alone. i had issues with smtp errors in all places i worked.

there is a LastStatus column in [dbo].[Subscriptions] table. you can make a job that runs every few minutes, checks this table and restarts all subscriptions which have smtp errors.

like SQLDiver, i think it's a good idea to store the data behind reports in a table. it's not a job for a reporting tool to store your data.